# Web form: checking for duplicate database entries

Tags: c#

I am a newbie.

I am attempting to check for duplicate database entries. My problem is:

1. I would like a success alert shown if the entry is successful.
2. A notification of duplicates shown if a duplicate exists.

My issue is: the alert for duplicates gets shown multiple times, however, the entry is never created if no duplicates exist.

This is my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// The following procedure creates the user account in the database The procedure first attempts to
/// perform a check for duplicates before submitting the registration info
/// </summary>
protected void BTN_CreateACNT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string InsertQuery = "";
    string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Reimburse"].ConnectionString;
    InsertQuery = "Insert into TBL_Logins (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Password) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @Password)";

    String FirstNameSTR = FN.Text.Trim();
    String LastNameSTR = LN.Text.Trim();
    String EMailAddressSTR = EmailAddress.Text.Trim();
    byte[] PassByte = StrToByteArray(PWD.Text.Trim());

    // CheckUser(EMailAddressSTR);
    while (CheckUser(EMailAddressSTR) == false)
    {
        SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, CN);
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", FirstNameSTR);
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastNameSTR);
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", EMailAddressSTR);
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PassByte);

        CN.Open();
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Account created successfully.');</script>");
        CN.Close();
    }
}

public bool CheckUser(String UserString)
{
    String UserSelect = "Select * from TBL_Logins where EmailAddress = @EmailAddress";
    int MailCount = 0;
    string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Reimburse"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    UserString = EmailAddress.Text.Trim();

    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(UserSelect, CN);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", UserString);
    CN.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = CMD.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (UserString == dr["EmailAddress"].ToString())
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('This EMail address is already taken. Please try again.');</script>");
            // return true;
        }
    }

    CN.Close();
    return true;
}

protected void BTN_CreateACNT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string InsertQuery = "";
    string ConnectionString =                 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Reimburse"].ConnectionString;
    InsertQuery = "Insert into TBL_Logins (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Password) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @Password)";

    String FirstNameSTR = FN.Text.Trim();
    String LastNameSTR = LN.Text.Trim();
    String EMailAddressSTR = EmailAddress.Text.Trim();
    byte[] PassByte = StrToByteArray(PWD.Text.Trim());

    //  CheckUser(EMailAddressSTR);
    while(CheckUser(EMailAddressSTR) == false)
    {
            SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, CN);                    
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", FirstNameSTR);
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastNameSTR);
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", EMailAddressSTR);
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PassByte);

            CN.Open();
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Account created successfully.');</script>");
            CN.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool CheckUser(String UserString)
    {
         String UserSelect = "Select * from TBL_Logins where EmailAddress = @EmailAddress";
        int MailCount = 0;
        string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Reimburse"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        UserString = EmailAddress.Text.Trim();
        SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(UserSelect,CN);
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", UserString);
        CN.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = CMD.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
                if (UserString == dr["EmailAddress"].ToString())
                {
                    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('This EMail address is already taken. Please try again.');</script>");
                    //                  return true;
                }           
        }

        CN.Close();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the CheckUser method always returns true and that's why the insertion does not work, update the method to return false by default:

```
while (dr.Read())
    {
            if (UserString == dr["EmailAddress"].ToString())
            {
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('This EMail address is already taken. Please try again.');</script>");
                return true; // return true if user exists
            }           
    }

 CN.Close();
 return false; // return false if the user does not exist
```

It is also recommended to use **using** block to dispose the DB connection instead of manually invoking the Close() method.